# How to convert queue<double[]> to double[][] in java?

Tags: java, queue

I am trying to convert `queue<double[]>` to `double[][]` using java 8 stream.
There are lots of literatures showing a way to convert `queue<double> to double[]` in many ways but I failed to convert the `double[]` to `double[][]`.

How to achieve issue above?

Comment: Does your solution really need to use streams? As shown in answer below all you need here is `double[][] array = yourQueue.toArray(new double[0][]);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this method `queue.toArray(new Double[0][0]);`.
Be careful.Do not use nonparametric overloaded method `queue.toArray()`.Because it can't convert to `Double[][]` but `Obejct[]`.

For example:

```java
LinkedBlockingQueue<Double[]> linkedBlockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        linkedBlockingQueue.put(new Double[]{1.1, 1.2});
        linkedBlockingQueue.put(new Double[]{2.1, 2.2});
        Double[][] doubleTwoDimensionArray = linkedBlockingQueue.toArray(new Double[0][0]);
```

> The `new Double[0][0]` only be used to appoint the type of conversion.

Answer (score 3):

Using `toArray()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue<double[]> q = new LinkedList<>();
    q.add(new double[]{1d, 2d, 3d, 9d, 7d});
    q.add(new double[]{4d, 5d, 6d});

    double[][] arr = q.toArray(new double[0][]);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
}
```

**Output:**

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 9.0, 7.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use streams, but it is not necessary.

```
double[][] arr = q.stream().toArray(double[][]::new);
```